# The ListView skips the bitmap images in the 2nd and 3rd rows. How to populate all the rows?

Tags: java, android, listview

The problem is that the `getView()` method is skipping to view the other images, in short, `getView()` only displays the 1st and last row of the ListView.

How to populate all the rows in the ListView?

This is my `getView()` code in my CustomListAdapter, there is no URL included.
I just directly download the images from the API.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    RowItemLoyalty rowItem = getItem(position);
    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new Holder();


        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.exp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.promotion_expiration);
        holder.tokensFor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tokensForRedeemOffer);
        holder.promotionImages = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.promotion_image);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.title.setText(rowItem.getDescription());
    holder.exp.setText(rowItem.getDateEnd());
    holder.tokensFor.setText(rowItem.getTokensFor());
    //holder.promotionImages.setImageBitmap(rowItem.getImage1());

    try {
        image_id.put(ConstantKeys.ID, rowItem.getImageId());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ImageDownloadRequest2 request = new ImageDownloadRequest2();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("USERPASS", 0);
    String email = sharedPreferences.getString("username", null);
    String password = sharedPreferences.getString("password", null);
    request.getToken(email, password, new ApiRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object object) {
            (new GetImageTask() {
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap data) {
                    super.onPostExecute(data);
                    if (data != null) {
                        Bitmap[] holderImage = new Bitmap[] {data};

                        holder.promotionImages.setImageBitmap(holderImage[0]);
                        Log.d("BITMAPVALUE", String.valueOf(data));
                    }else
                    {
                        holder.promotionImages.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_icon);
                    }
                }
            }).execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {
            Log.e("Get Logo", error);
        }
    });


    Log.d("IMAGESTASHLOYALTY", String.valueOf(rowItem.getImageId()));

    return convertView;
}
```

And this is my AsyncTask

```
private static class GetImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>
{
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            ImageDownload2 manager = ImageDownload2.getInstance();
            Bitmap result = null;

            try
            {
      result = manager.apiCall("File/DownloadFiles", image_id.toString(), "C");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }
}
```

Comment: Exact same problem I was facing a few weeks before...

Comment: How many items/rows are visible? You have so many items that the user has to scroll?

Comment: @greenapps the app has 4 items, and the getView only shows 1st and last item so the other 2(in the middle) has no image

Comment: To better see your problem and to make the problem worse add more items so the user has to scoll. Only when your code survives scrolling the code is ok. Use my answer to change the code.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay is it solved already?

Answer (score 0):

Standard misconcept of recycling the views. You give the AsyncTask the `holder` as parameter. But holder will be a different holder by the time the asynctask is ready with downloading the image.

You better give `int position` as parameter to the AsyncTask as then you can place the image at the rigth position.

Comment: That was not necessary. I already told you not to use the holder.

Comment: but the holder, holds the imageview variable

Comment: Which will not be valid anymore at the time the image is downloaded. I said that before. Please read about items recycling of listviews. Or use one of the many examples on the internet for lazy image loading.